# How to generate a random caseid in textbox with user click

Tags: android

When the user clicks on `information`, it should generate a random number - is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Implement the onClickListener() for the view you want the user to click. To generate random numbers, add this inside it:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int  n = rand.nextInt(10); // this will return a random number between 0 and 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int min = 1;
int max = 100;

Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min) + min;
```

Note that `nextInt(int max)` returns an `int` between 0 inclusive and max exclusive.